# Doctrine QueryBuilder in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a problem with Symfony and DQL.
I got 2 tables.

TableA:
id: int,
status: string,
referenceNumber: int
tableB: []tableB

TableB:
id:int,
type: int,
tableA_id: int

Tables are in one(tableA) to many(tableB) relation.

And I need to find every TableA where

```
TableA.status = Complete
AND (TableA.referenceNumber IS NULL OR COUNT(TableB.type = 22) = 0)

    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from('TestBundle:TableA', 'a');
    $queryBuilder->select('a','b');
    $queryBuilder->leftjoin('a.tableB', 'b');
    $queryBuilder->andWHERE('a.status = 'Complete')
    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
```

I don't know how to write rest of query.

Comment: You made a typo, change to `$queryBuilder->andWhere('a.status = "Complete"')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just can do:

```
$query->where("a.status = 'Complete'")
      ->andWhere("a.referenceNumber IS NULL OR COUNT(b.type = 22) = 0");
```

If you use variable, use prepared query with:

```
$query->where("a.status = :status")
      ->setParameter("status", $status);
```

Hope it's what you want